# Validation for multiple check box using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have 3 check boxes and while validating on submit, the validation message is displaying in unusual way. i am getting the validation message for other types correctly

My html code

```
<label class="control-label col-xs-4" for="color">Color:</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="CMYK">CMYK</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="RGB">RGB</label>
  <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="Special Colors">Special Colors</label>
</div>
```

Validation code

```
$("#adupload").validate({
    errorClass: "my-error-class",
    rules: {'color[]': { 
         required: true
    }
    messages: {'color[]': "Please select a Color"}
```

My validation error screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you plz setup a jsfiddle/plunkr.

Comment: Would appreciate some css code.

Comment: my css is .my-error-class {
 font-size: 13px;
    color:#FF0000;  /* red */
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add the [errorPlacement](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) property, to customize the placement of errors.

```
messages: {'color[]': "<div>Please select a Color</div>"},
    errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
             if (element.attr("type") == "checkbox") 
               error.insertAfter($(".checkbox-inline").last());
             else
               error.insertAfter(element);
    }
```